# Rigid body simulation requires mass input every time

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I created a rigid body simulation using hinge. But it only simulates when I enter the mass of the rigid body. Otherwise it never shows simulation. why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Rigid body always need mass to work properly.

You can`t apply forces to 0 mass rigid body.

Rigid-body dynamics studies the movement of systems of interconnected bodies under the action of external forces. The assumption that the bodies are rigid, which means that they do not deform under the action of applied forces, simplifies the analysis by reducing the parameters that describe the configuration of the system to the translation and rotation of reference frames attached to each body.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics)

**EDIT**

Try if this Works [image]

Comment: Yes I understand. The problem is that I have already put the mass. But when I press Art+A it does not show anything. I have to press enter on the mass section to show the simulation, just enter, the mass is already there. Is this normal?

Comment: I suggest that you put more information, screenshots, upload a blend file with the minimum to reproduce the problem through [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), i press <kdb>Alt</kdb> + <kdb>A</kdb> and it play the animation.